# Grouping data in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Query shows perfect and exact results but problem is that it shows it like this:

it shows records of SINGLE person on Single date
e.g.

```
002 AbdurRehman ...... 2013-09-11
003 Hayat  .......     2013-09-11
```

i want it like this

```
002 AbdurRehman ...... 2013-09-11
002 AbdurRehman  ......2013-09-12
002 AbdurRehman  ......2013-09-13
002 AbdurRehman  ......2013-09-14
003 Hayat        ......2013-09-11
003 Hayat        ......2013-09-12
003 Hayat        ......2013-09-13
```

like 1st whole date records for one person then whole dates record for 2nd persona and so on.

Query:

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , t4.ShiftId as ShiftID
        , t4.StAtdTime as ShStartTime
        , t4.EndAtdTime as ShEndTime
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
inner join AtdShiftSect t4
ON t3.ShiftId = t4.ShiftId
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
        , t4.ShiftId 
        , t4.StAtdTime 
        , t4.EndAtdTime
)
SELECT 
 EmplID
,EmplName
,ShiftId As ShiftID
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) TotalWorkingTime
,[DateVisited]
,CASE WHEN [InTime] IS NOT NULL AND [TimeOut] IS NOT NULL THEN
     CONVERT(char(5),CASE WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime And ShiftID = 'S002' Then  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) 
                          WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime And ShiftID = 'S001' Then  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) 
      ELSE '00:00' END, 108) 
 ELSE 'ABSENT' END AS OverTime
 FROM times order by  DateVisited, EmplID, ShiftID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ordering in the end of your code:

```
ORDER BY EmplID, DateVisited, ShiftID
```